# Homepage only displays correctly when logged in

Tags: magento2, cache, home-page

I just disabled a new extension due to some conflicts it had with a custom extension we have installed. Immediately after, I noticed the website was much slower, and after checking the cache, I noticed that all but compiled_config were disabled. I re-enabled them, and now much homepage doesn't display unless I'm logged in to the website. Any ideas on how to resolve this? I redisabled the applicable caches, but no luck.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: please run : content deploy and s:s:d and change the website mode to production

Answer (score 0):

Another developer was able to assist me, so I am updating this post. The problem was that I wasn't switching to the file system owner when running commands. This led to a permissions issue that prevented certain blocks from displaying.

Essentially, I failed to follow the very first instruction on the [Magento DevDocs module page](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html).

Hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.